# Ошибка raise ValueError('`x` (images tensor) and `y` (labels) ' ValueError: `x` (images tensor) and `y` (labels) should have the same length

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, keras

Судя по всему я должен как-то добиться одинаковой длины для входа и выхода, но я не совсем понимаю как

```py
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-d", "--dataset", required=True,help="images")
ap.add_argument("-m", "--model", required=True,help="model")
ap.add_argument("-l", "--label-bin", required=True,help="bin_label")

args = vars(ap.parse_args())
data = []
labels = []

imagePaths = sorted(list(paths.list_images(args["dataset"])))
random.seed(42)
random.shuffle(imagePaths)

for imagePath in imagePaths:
    image=Image.open(imagePath)
    image = np.array(image)
    image = cv2.resize(image, (64, 64))
    image = img_to_array(image)/ 255.0
    data.append(image)

    label = imagePath.split(os.path.sep)[-2]
    labels.append(label)

data = np.array(data, dtype="float") / 255.0
labels = np.array(labels)
trainX, testX, trainY, testY = train_test_split(data,labels, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)

lb = LabelBinarizer()
trainY = lb.fit_transform(trainY)
testY = lb.transform(testY)

aug = ImageDataGenerator(width_shift_range=0.1,height_shift_range=0.1, shear_range=0.2, zoom_range=0.2,horizontal_flip=False, fill_mode="nearest")


model = Sequential()

classes=len(lb.classes_)
inputShape = (64, 64, 3)
chanDim = -1


model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding="same",input_shape=inputShape))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding="same"))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding="same"))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding="same"))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding="same"))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding="same"))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(classes))
model.add(Activation("softmax"))


sp = 0.01
epox = 75
bchs = 32

opt = SGD(lr=sp, decay=sp / epox)
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=opt,metrics=["accuracy"])

#plot_model(model, to_file="ner_model.png")

model.fit(aug.flow(trainX, trainY, batch_size=bchs),validation_data=(testX, testY), steps_per_epoch=len(trainX) // bchs,epochs=epox)
```

сначала думал что это может быть из-за `classes=len(lb.classes_)`, но при ручной подстановке получился такой же результат

полный текст ошибки:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\Антон\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\ner_train.py", line 194, in 
> model.fit(aug.flow(trainX, trainY, batch_size=bchs),validation_data=(testX, testY), steps_per_epoch=len(trainX) // bchs,epochs=epox)
> File "C:\Users\Антон\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\preprocessing\image.py", line 853, in flow
> return NumpyArrayIterator(
> File "C:\Users\Антон\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\preprocessing\image.py", line 449, in **init**
> super(NumpyArrayIterator, self).**init**(
> File "C:\Users\Антон\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\numpy_array_iterator.py", line 86, in **init**
> raise ValueError('`x` (images tensor) and `y` (labels) '
> ValueError: `x` (images tensor) and `y` (labels) should have the same length. Found: x.shape = (64, 64, 3), y.shape = (49, 31)

Comment: Ну хотя бы для начала покажите `trainX.shape` и `trainY.shape`. И вот `model.summury()` - это же явная опечатка, тут должна быть ошибка. Вы код точно скопировали?

Comment: Да, вы правы, я забыл закомментировать при переносе сюда model.summury, и обнаружил что trainX - лист

Answer (score 0):

оказалось что часть изображений в оттенках серого, проблема решилась:

```
image = Image.open(imagePath).convert('RGB')
```